# Alter the generated composer.json on packages.drupal.org for third-party modules

Tags: 7, composer

*This question is similar to [Support composer_manager AND drupal-composer/drupal-project with contrib module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/276910/support-composer-manager-and-drupal-composer-drupal-project-with-contrib-module), but I am asking it with a different angle this time. Imo this justifies a separate question, as an answer to this could be generally useful beyond my specific use case.*

### Technical background

packages.drupal.org re-publishes module packages from drupal.org with auto-generated composer.json.

The main "module package" becomes a composer package with `"type": "drupal-module"`. Each "submodule" (module in a subdirectory) becomes a package with `"type": "metapackage"`.

The composer.json for each submodule is generated from the *.info file. E.g. if the *.info file says `dependencies[] = composer_manager`, then the composer.json for this metapackage will require `drupal/composer_manager`. It seems that composer.json in the submodule is ignored.

For the main / root package, perhaps an existing composer.json is not ignored. Not sure about that.

Sometimes the generated composer.json is not exactly what I want.

The functionality on packages.drupal.org is provided by https://www.drupal.org/project/project_composer.
There are database tables that contain information about modules uploaded to drupal.org (via https://www.drupal.org/project/project), and project_composer derives Composer data from this.

### Question

Is it possible for a contrib module to alter the composer.json that will be generated for the main module package and for a submodule metapackage?

E.g.:

- Prevent a module dependency from the *.info file to be added as a Composer requirement.
- Add an additional 3rd party Composer requirement.